# How to pipe binary data into numpy arrays without tmp storage?

Tags: python, numpy, stdin, stringio

There are several similar questions but none of them answers this simple question directly:

How can i catch a commands output and stream that content into numpy arrays **without** creating a temporary string object to read from?

So, what I would like to do is this:

```
import subprocess
import numpy
import StringIO

def parse_header(fileobject):
    # this function moves the filepointer and returns a dictionary
    d = do_some_parsing(fileobject)
    return d

sio = StringIO.StringIO(subprocess.check_output(cmd))
d = parse_header(sio)
# now the file pointer is at the start of data, parse_header takes care of that.
# ALL of the data is now available in the next line of sio
dt = numpy.dtype([(key, 'f8') for key in d.keys()])

# i don't know how do make this work:
data = numpy.fromxxxx(sio , dt)

# if i would do this, I create another copy besides the StringIO object, don't I?
# so this works, but isn't this 'bad' ?
datastring = sio.read()
data = numpy.fromstring(datastring, dtype=dt)
```

I tried it with StringIO and cStringIO but both are not accepted by numpy.frombuffer and numpy.fromfile.

Using StringIO object I first have to read the stream into a string and then use numpy.fromstring, but I would like to avoid creating the intermediate object (several Gigabytes).

An alternative for me would be if I can stream sys.stdin into numpy arrays, but that does not work with numpy.fromfile either (seek needs to be implemented).

Are there any work-arounds for this? I can't be the first one trying this (unless this is a PEBKAC case?)

Solution:
This is the current solution, it's a mix of unutbu's instruction how to use the Popen with PIPE and the hint of eryksun to use bytearray, so I don't know who to accept!? :S

```
proc = sp.Popen(cmd, stdout = sp.PIPE, shell=True)
d = parse_des_header(proc.stdout)
rec_dtype = np.dtype([(key,'f8') for key in d.keys()])
data = bytearray(proc.stdout.read())
ndata = np.frombuffer(data, dtype = rec_dtype)
```

I didn't check if the data is really not creating another copy, don't know how. But what I noticed that this works much faster than everything I tried before, so many thanks to both the answers' authors!

Update 2022:
I just tried above solution steps without the bytearray() step and it just works fine. Thanks to Python 3 I guess?

Comment: Have you considered [numpy.fromiter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html#numpy-fromiter)?

Comment: Could you post a (simplified) example of what kind of function (or input) we are dealing with?

Comment: Maybe use `Popen` with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` (i.e. no temporary string as with `check_output`), read in the header, then load the rest into a `bytearray` to use with `np.frombuffer`. The NumPy array will share the same memory as the `bytearray`.

Comment: your method works, @eryksun. put it into an answer to get some acceptance points. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Popen` with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`. Read in the header, then load the rest into a `bytearray` to use with `np.frombuffer`.

Additional comments based on your edit:

If you're going to call `proc.stdout.read()`, it's equivalent to using `check_output()`. Both create a temporary string. If you preallocate `data`, you could use `proc.stdout.readinto(data)`. Then if the number of bytes read into `data` is less than `len(data)`, free the excess memory, else extend `data` by whatever is left to be read.

```
data = bytearray(2**32) # 4 GiB
n = proc.stdout.readinto(data)
if n < len(data):
    data[n:] = ''        
else:
    data += proc.stdout.read()
```

You could also come at this starting with a pre-allocated `ndarray` `ndata` and use `buf = np.getbuffer(ndata)`. Then `readinto(buf)` as above.

Here's an example to show that the memory is shared between the `bytearray` and the  `np.ndarray`:

```
>>> data = bytearray('\x01')
>>> ndata = np.frombuffer(data, np.int8)
>>> ndata
array([1], dtype=int8)
>>> ndata[0] = 2
>>> data
bytearray(b'\x02')
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your data can easily fit in RAM, I think the easiest way to load the data into a numpy array is to use a [ramfs](http://www.linux-mag.com/cache/7388/1.html).

On Linux,

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ramfs
sudo mount -t ramfs -o size=5G ramfs /mnt/ramfs
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/ramfs
```

Then, for example, if this is the producer of the binary data:

**writer.py:**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import struct
N = random.randrange(100)
print('a b')
for i in range(2*N):
    print(struct.pack('<d',random.random()), end = '')
```

Then you could load it into a numpy array like this:

**reader.py:**

```
import subprocess
import numpy

def parse_header(f):
    # this function moves the filepointer and returns a dictionary
    header = f.readline()
    d = dict.fromkeys(header.split())
    return d

filename = '/mnt/ramfs/data.out'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:  
    cmd = 'writer.py'
    proc = subprocess.Popen([cmd], stdout = f)
    proc.communicate()
with open(filename, 'r') as f:      
    header = parse_header(f)
    dt = numpy.dtype([(key, 'f8') for key in header.keys()])
    data = numpy.fromfile(f, dt)
```

Comment: Have you checked the memory usage when you use this to create a very large array?  Note that `fromiter` has a `count` keyword (check the docstring).  If you don't use it, the array is resized as it is built.  You might still have the problem of temporarily using a lot more memory than the final size of the array.

Comment: Isn't this impossible because the premise is, that after parsing the header, all the data is in the next line. There are **no** further line endings that can be parsed!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: I don't think we can use the `count` parameter in this case because we don't know how many lines of data are going to outputted by the process.

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye: In the comments under the question you state you do not know "how many lines I will receive". But in the comment under my post you state, "after parsing the header, all the data is in the next line." I'm confused. Which one is it?

Comment: @unutbu: Right.  I didn't mean to imply that you could use it.

Comment: I admit it's not yet very clear, but the example code states clearly that all the data is in the next line. the size of the dtype determines the size of a line, but no EOL characters appear from the stream. the read() command has to be sized according to the size of dtype. And numpy.fromfile beautifully does that correctly when reading this stream from disk after having it piped into a file. It just won't work with a direct sys.stdin unfortunately.

Comment: i don't understand the apparent double use of iterations, once via the iter() function and once via the generator? What does that do?

Comment: The 2-argument call to `iter(readline, "")` returns an iterator which yields the result of `readline()` until it reaches the value `""`. So it is just a way to feed lines to `process_data`. Now that I understand the problem, this is useless :)

Comment: Roughly, what is the size of the data coming out of `cmd`? Can it all fit in RAM? If so, you could perhaps make a [ramfs](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7388/), direct the output to a file in the ramfs, and then use `np.fromfile` to load it a numpy array...

Comment: Yes it should fit. It's 3.6 GB in binary, all being doubles and I have 94 GB of RAM. Will try that one.