# Load data to a numpy array by piping the output of an external program

Tags: python, numpy, stdout

I have a program that outputs a huge array of float32 preceded by a 40 bytes header. The program writes to stdout.

I can dump the output into a file, open it in python, skip the 40 bytes of the header, and load it into numpy using numpy.fromfile(). However that takes a lot of time.

So what I would like to do is to load the array directly into numpy by reading the stdout of the program that generates it. However I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

Thanks!

Comment: something like this [How to pipe binary data into numpy arrays without tmp storage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059444/how-to-pipe-binary-data-into-numpy-arrays-without-tmp-storage)

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can [memory-map](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) the file instead of reading it all.  This will take almost no time:

```
np.memmap(filename, np.float32, offset=40)
```

Of course actually reading data from the result will take some time, but probably this will be hidden by interleaving the I/O with computation.

If you really don't want the data to ever be written to disk, you could use `subprocess.Popen()` to run your program with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and pass the resulting stdout file-like object directly to `numpy.fromfile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all that responded/commented.

I followed [downshift](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1248974/downshift)'s advice and looked into the link he provides...

And came up with the folowing:

```
nLayers=<Number of layers in program output>
nRows=<Number of rows in layer> 
nCols=<Number of columns in layer>
nBytes=<Number of bytes for each value>
noDataValue=<Value used to code no data in program output>
DataType=<appropriate numpy data type for values>

perLayer=nRows*nCols*nBytes

proc = sp.Popen(cmd+args, stdout = sp.PIPE, shell=True)
data=bytearray()
for i in range(0,nLayers):
   dump40=proc.stdout.read(40)
   data=data+bytearray(proc.stdout.read(perLayer))
ndata = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=DataType)
ndata[ndata == noDataValue]=np.nan
ndata.shape = (nLayers,nRows,nCols)
```

the key here is using the `numpy.frombuffer` which uses the same read buffer to create the darray, and thus avoids having to duplicate the data in memory.