# NumPy: Read binary file into existing array

Tags: python, numpy, binaryfiles, hpc, fromfile

Given a binary file of numerical values, I can read it in using [`numpy.fromfile()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html). This allocates a new array for the data. Say I already have an array `a` and I want to read into this array. I'd had to do something like

```py
import numpy as np

size       = 1_000_000_000
size_chunk = 1_000_000
a = np.empty(size, dtype=np.double)
with open('filename', 'rb') as f:
    tmp = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.double, count=size_chunk)
a[:size_chunk] = tmp
```

where to make things general `a` is larger than the data read into `tmp`. I want to avoid the memory penalty caused by `tmp` by reading directly into `a`. Note that though

```py
a[:size_chunk] = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.double, count=size_chunk)
```

hides the `tmp` variable, the unnecessary temporary memory is still there.

I imagine something like

```py
np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.double, count=size_chunk, into=a[:chunk_size])
```

though no such `into` keyword is implemented.

How can I achieve this? I'm open to using SciPy or other Python packages as well. I'll note that the H5Py package has a [`read_direct()`](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#h5py.Dataset.read_direct) which does what I want, except my data file is a raw binary and not in HDF5 format.

Comment: I think you'd have to read the data yourself using `open`, `struct` and assign it to your array in a loop. As you noticed, there is no option to pass an already allocated array to `fromfile`. If memory is such an issue, you'd have to use smaller chunks.

Comment: I'm afraid doing it manually in Python using `open` and `struct` will be quite slow, compared to a NumPy/C implementation.

Comment: `h5py` has a lot of `cython` code, so that `read_direct` is using lower level array access.

Comment: @jmd_dk Maybe `numba` can speed that up, or you have to extend the `numpy` function yourself (and if you fancy try to the PR into upstream).

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Numba cannot help with the many invocations of `struct`. I think the right thing to do is to write it in C/Cython and provide a Python wrapper. I'm just sad that NumPy doesn't allow me to provide the memory buffer, as it already has the underlying efficient read implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading about the [*buffer protocol*](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) and it mentions [*readinto*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.readinto); there are several questions on SO for this kind of problem,e.g [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059444/how-to-pipe-binary-data-into-numpy-arrays-without-tmp-storage) and some of them suggest the use of *readinto*.

---

Original answer: while this should be possible with a custom C extension it is also an overkill.

I don't think this is possible with numpy alone and you would have to do your own C extension. I have looked over the [numpy reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/) so there might be something I missed but by design python would allocate memory for your buffer and if the numpy developers respect this design choice then there's not much to do other than writing you own C extension to support this very case.